# Allow external inbound connection to Azure Windows Server 2019 Virtual Machine on specific port

Tags: sql-server, firewall, azure, azure-networking

I want to allow TCP connection to 1433 port (SQL Server) on the Azure Windows Virtual Machine. TCP is enabled for SQL Server and I can telnet to this port from the local machine as well (`telnet localhost 1433`).

### Inbound rule in Windows firewall

[image]

### Inbound rule in Azure portal

[image]

What should I do more to be able to connect externally?

UPDATE:

### Network effective security rules

[image]

### Networking

[image]

### SQL Server

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Whats the issue you are having?

Comment: I can't connect externally

Comment: Ok, what error are you getting?

Comment: The same error if I wouldn't do anything. Can't connect. Telnet can't connect either

Comment: Just a wild guess, have you double checked that the Windows Firewall allows this connection?

Comment: Yes, check my image in the description, there is a Inbound rule for that or are you talking about something else? I also turned off firewall in Windows temporarily and it didn't help as well

Comment: Doing a telnet test to localhost doesn't make sense at all. This will resolve to 127.0.0.1 which is a non routeable IP address. Also the MSSQL service very likely has bound to 0.0.0.0 (Any) instead of localhost. Take a client that is connected to the internet and do your telnet test again against the *public IP* of your VM

Comment: I can't connect via telnet using public IP. I've tested it with localhost just to make sure that the port is open at least locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A word of warning: Opening up 1433/TCP to the internet (with source: Any) is quite a security risk. Think twice about your intentions here!**

1. Install SSMS on the mentioned VM and ensure that you can connect locally to your MSSSQL server. Also ensure that `Allow remote connections to this server` is ticked (in SSMS go to the properties of your server > Connections > Remote server connections).
2. Double check that your local windows firewall allows the connection (not NSG! turn of the windows firewall entirely for testing)
3. Check if a NSG attached to the **subnet** may blocks your connection
4. Use the IP flow tool provided by Network Watcher to verify your connectivity
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-ip-flow-verify-overview
5. Double check if by any chance you have more than one NIC attached to the VM and that ACLs apply to the correct/expected NIC
6. Have a look at the `Effective Security Rules` (VM > Networking > Effective Security Rules)

==> It seems your **source** port is set to 1433/TCP but really should be 0-65535.

Comment: The connectivity tool said that it is blocked by "DenyAllBound" rule (please check img in question). My question would be, how the RDP is working then and is not blocked, but SQL Server rule is blocked?

Comment: See me updated answer point 5.

Comment: Also ensure `Allow remote connections for this server` is set from within SSMS

Comment: I'm not sure about 5th point where exactly can I find that, but as far as I understood it is attached to single one. I've modified the question and added more screenshots

Comment: See my updated answer. Your source port is set to 1433 but should be 0-65535

Comment: thanks, it's working now

Comment: Could you please explain why didn't exact port number work?

Comment: Usually the client selects a random source port from a range of ports and not one specific port, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port for more information